# changing layout/content in android tab

Tags: android

I currently have this code that creates 4 tabs using tabactivity:

```
public class toknapp extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, login2.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("login").setIndicator("Login")
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, QuestsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Quests")
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BadgeActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Badges")
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, InfoActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Tokn")
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

I wanted to change the tab content/layout (to myquests.xml) in the "Quests" tab after this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            String res=response.toString();
           // res = res.trim();
            res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");   
            if(!res.equals("0")){
                un.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                key.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                merchant.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                merchant_id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                JSONObject jObject;
                try {
                    jObject = new JSONObject(res);
                    String data = jObject.getString("merchant_name");
                    String Id = jObject.getString("merchant_id");
                    merchant_id.setText(Id);
                    merchant.setText(data);
                } catch (Exception  e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the activitygroup like  this

view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ReferenceName", new Intent(view.getContext(), myquests.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
setContentView(view);